# Process video streams with Xuggler API

Tags: java, video, video-streaming, video-processing, xuggler

I'm trying to build showcase video streaming from a server to a client, but I need to process the stream before sending. I like to do all in java, and client be an Android device.

I just heard about a library called `Xuggler` which is Java-based and looks promising. Does it provide any functionalities to access the video streams and do some image processing on them before transmission?

Please introduce any other Java-based media streaming / processing libraries if you know of.

Answer (score 1):

For Java video processing, despite being long deprecated, Xuggler has been the best solution that I've found, someone else might know of an alternative.

Since it's not supported anymore you have to do a few things to get started. First find a Xuggler-5.4.jar, Also you need the Java 7 Jdk to run it, it will not work with Java 8, then you need the sl4j-api and sl4j-simple Jars.

It has a complicated but well documented api, but the main gist is you use the  MediaToolAdapter interface, create an IMedia Reader and Writer, add something implementing the interface to the reader as a listener, and in the implemented methods for audio and video you can process the data in each frame and pass it to the writer.

This example is a good place to start:
https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/ModifyAudioAndVideo.java

Comment: Thanks. Can I use Android for the receiver? It needs to receive streams and play.

Comment: I'm not sure about using Xuggler for streaming. It can probably be done, but I don't think it's a built feature. I have only used it to output files, but There is a google group where people might have tried that might be worth searching. Another option is Gstreamer or OpenCv for Java. Openframeworks might be a good environment to use, but that is c++

Comment: Not sure if any of those has built in streaming functions. Also fluent-ffmpeg for nodejs can definitely stream and process at the same time, but that is javascript.